# Can an iOS device monitor its own beacon (one that it is advertising)?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am hoping I can make an iOS app run a self-test to see if it's able to listen to beacons, by:

1. Advertising a beacon (with a randomly-generated UUID) via the `CBPeripheralManager` API, and
2. Monitoring and ranging for that same beacon.

In other words, make the device listen for the beacon that it, its very self, is advertising.

I do get a success response when I start advertising: the system calls my `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` handler with `peripheral.state` set to `PoweredOn`.

I also get a success response when I start monitoring for beacons: the system calls my `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:` handler. I also get `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` calls.

However, it always gives me a zero-length list of beacons in range.

Does anyone know: does iOS prevent a device from monitoring or ranging itself as a beacon?

Comment: Did you find that its "immediate" proximity in didRangeBeacons?  I hope so :-).  The next thing to try is do the advertising from a different app on the same phone and see what happens, then two phones.. If you get a non-zero set of beacons in either of those circumstances then either its a bug or its a sketchy proposition to broadcast and range from the same app/device.

Comment: I don't believe you can range your own apps beacon. @danh an app cannot advertise a beacon in the background, so you cannot monitor a beacon advertised by another app while that app isn't in the foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Neither `CoreLocation` nor `CoreBluetooth` will pick up an advertisement transmitted by the same device.  This should not really be surprising as the device has a single Bluetooth radio, so it cannot transmit and receive at the same time.